# How to remove forced disk read only mode? (failure might be imminent msg on boot)

Tags: boot, bios, smart, read-only, samsung-ssd

Woke my PC up from sleep and got blue screen. On reboot it said that my boot disk's failure is imminent and didn't let me chose it as a boot disk even when I tried to force it through bios. I hooked up an old HDD that had an OS and upon further inspection it appears that the primary issue is my disks free space.

PassMark DiskCheckup sees nothing wrong.

CrystalDiskInfo shows this:

[image]

Disk Management shows as read only:

[image]

I'm hopeful this means that I can recover the drive with files intact. I have backed up what I can but as it already states, it is put into "read only mode". This is problematic, because I cannot free up any space, it doesn't let me delete anything. I've tried [removing read only attribute through cmd diskpart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AClB.png) and added a write protect key in regedit following a guide online but it doesn't help, it's still in read only mode.

I have a suspicion that the SMART feature of my nvme has made it read only on a deeper level where I cannot undo it from OS. I cannot find anything about it online to see if I can force remove read only mode in the BIOS either.

Any ideas how I should proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your disk has failed and needs to replaced.

It would have been better to include a screenshot of the SMART attributes,
but the error message is pretty explicit :

```
Available spare capacity has fallen below the threshold.
Media has been placed in Read Only Mode.
```

Every disk has thousands of spare sectors that are used for remapping
bad sectors by the firmware.
In your case, the number of bad sectors has used up almost all of these
spare sectors, so the firmware has placed the disk in a read-only state.

There is no way to undo this state from Windows, since it's the firmware
that placed the disk into the read-only state.

If you have important data on the disk, take immediately a backup.
The disk itself should be replaced and junked.

Comment: Free space is unimportant to mechanical drives, but it is important to some degree, when dealing with SSDs. This answer properly and accurately points out, your drive has failed. Your only real recourse is to clone it to a new drive.